# Cordova speech recognition plugin "Invalid action"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, speech-recognition

I'm trying to use this plugin: https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-speechrecognition

All set-up ok, but when I call `isRecognitionAvailable()`, I'm getting a promise rejection with the error msg: `'Invalid action'`.

I've checked all the permissions and minSDKVersion are correct in the generated AndroidManifest.xml and all that stuff.

**Note: I'm on Wifi.**

**Here's my code:**

```
let options = {
  language: 'en-US',
  matches: 1,
  prompt: '',          
  showPopup: false,
  showPartial: false
}
this.speechRecognition.startListening(options).subscribe(
    (matches: Array<string>) => {
      // matches arrive here....
    },
    (onerror) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(onerror));
    }
);
```

**Manifest:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="io.ionic.starter" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="cordova.plugins.Diagnostic$LocationProviderChangedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="cordova.plugins.Diagnostic$NFCStateChangedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing and re-adding the android platform fixed this issue, now I have another which is different.

Answer (score 2):

As far as checked, this plugin requires network to work. Check out this [link](https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-speechrecognition/issues/11) for more info on this.

You can also check out a sample speech recognizer app which uses a different plugin in this [github repo](https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_Speech_Recognizer)

Try requesting for permission as mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-speechrecognition/issues/35) as I dont see this code in your sample.

Comment: I literally don't understand what you mean.  I said in my original question that I'm connected to wifi already.

Comment: @Dave I overlooked that. Could you try once with mobile data?

Comment: Already tried that, with wifi turned off.  I have checked the android manifest permissions are correct too.

Comment: @Dave I need to dig more on this before I give any suggestion. Dont understand the point in down voting even after providing the link to a working sample. Feels demotivated

Comment: Simply because the answer doesn't take into account the question text that clearly states I have a connection.  That's all. Thanks.  I also tried your working example and I get an immediate "Invalid action" error when it runs.

Comment: @Dave did you checked this link - https://youtu.be/dPbT_kElSXA?list=FLt2RBYE7N1voAWiBqeGlTHg by any chance that has a live working sample code demo. In your code I dont see any permission related code too

Comment: Thanks, please see updated question text.  Also, if you edit your response, I can upvote.

Comment: yes, see this now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44454588/speech-recognition-network-error-on-startlistening-android-6-7