# Speech Recognition: “Network error” on startListening() Android 6/7

Tags: android, typescript, ionic2, cordova-plugins, speech-recognition

When I run the code below, as soon as the beep sounds to start recording the mic, I get "Network error":

I have no idea what's wrong here. I've:

- added the: cordova plugin + npm module correctly,
- granted permissions in the app for microphone
- tried connected to WIfi
- tried connected to 4g
- tried removing and re-adding the android platform to the project
- tried on 2 different phones (samsung s5 android 6 / sony xperia z5c
  android 7)

Here's my basic code, nothing special here:

```
  setupSpeechRecognition() {
    this.speechRecognition.requestPermission().then(() => {
        this.speechRecognition.startListening().subscribe(
            (matches) => {
              // matches here...
            },
            (onerror) => {
              alert("Error: " + JSON.stringify(onerror));
            }
        );          
      },
      () => {}
    );      
  }
```

And here's my AndroidManifest.xml for kicks:

```
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="io.ionic.starter" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="cordova.plugins.Diagnostic$LocationProviderChangedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="cordova.plugins.Diagnostic$NFCStateChangedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.ADAPTER_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24570261/android-speechrecognizer-network-error

Comment: And what do you see in logcat?

Comment: Did you find solution?